# Upload File to AWS S3 using Server Side Encryptions

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3

I am new to Amazon AWS , I can upload file through AWS Command line using aws cp from local machine to S3 bucket

```
aws s3 cp "E:/AWS/test.txt" s3://mybucket/test.txt
```

Now I want to encrypt the files Server Side Encryptions, Amazon Customer Provided Key (SSE-C) and  AWS-Managed Encryption Keys (SSE-KMS). Can anybody help How I can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html).

You would add the appropriate parameter like `--sse AES256` for basic server side encryption.

Comment: I have already seen this documentation, but confused how to generate key and use it, can you please share the command as example exactly for SSE-C and SSE-KMS to upload file?

Answer (score 0):

I have find the solution using following way for SSE-C:

to copy file from local file to S3 bucket:

```
aws s3 cp "e:/AWS/test.txt" s3://mybucket/test.txt --sse-c AES256 --sse-c-key B3DBCB8D7594F0A21D3D9E0EA3B75444
```

to download from S3 bucket

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/test.txt "e:/AWS/test.txt"--sse-c AES256 --sse-c-key B3DBCB8D7594F0A21D3D9E0EA3B75444
```